# Merging 2 lists using Levenshtein Distance on terms in list

Tags: c#

Good afternoon,

I'm hoping i can get an assist on this from someone. If not some example code then some general direction i should be going with this.

Essentially i have two large lists (roughly 10-20,000 records each) of string terms and ID's. These lists are coming from two different data providers. The lists are obviously related to one another topically, however each data provider has slight variations in their terms naming conventions. For example list1 would have a term *"The Term (Some Subcategory)"* and list2 would have *"the term - some subcategory"*. Additionally list1 could have *"The Term (Some Subcategory)"* and *"The Term (Some Subcategory 2)"* while list2 only has *"the term - some subcategory"*.

Both lists have the following properties - "term" and "id". What i need to do is compare every term in both lists and if a reasonable match is found generate a new list containing "term", "list1id", "list2id" properties. If no match is found for a term i need it also to be added to the list with either "list1id" or "list2id" null/blank (which will indicate the origin of the unmatched term).

I'm willing to us a NuGet package to occumplish this or if anyone has a good example of what i need that would be helpful too. Essentially i'm attempting to generate a new merged list based on fuzzy terms within each while retaining the ID's of the matched terms somehow.

My research has dug up some similar articles and source such as https://matthewgladney.com/blog/data-science/using-levenshtein-distance-in-csharp-to-associate-lists-of-terms/ and https://github.com/wolfgarbe/symspell but neither seem to fit what i need.

Where do i go from here with this? Any help would be awesome!

Nugs

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty broad, but I will attempt a broad answer to, at least, get you started.  I've done this sort of thing before.

Do it in two stages: first normalize, then match.  By doing this you eliminate known but irrelevant causes of differences.   By normalize, *for example*, make everything caps, remove whitespace, remove non-alphanumeric characters, etc.  You'll need to be a little creative and work within any constraints you might have (is "Amy (pony)" the *same thing* as "Amy pony"?).  Then calculate 
the distance.

Create a class with a few properties to contain the value from the left list, the value from the right list, the normalized values, the score, etc.

When you get a match, create an instance of that class, add it to a list or equivalent, remove the old values from the original lists, then keep going.

Try to write your code so you keep track of intermediate values (e.g. the normalized values, etc).  This will make it easier to debug, and will allow you to log everything *after* you've done processing.

Once you're done, you can then throw away intermediate values and keep just the things you identified as a match.